# How to handle Callback/Redirects from dpd-passport via Google strategy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, passport.js, deployd

I am building a project using Deployd for assistance with my API, and dpd-passport for authentication.

I seem to have everything authenticating, with session keys behind handed out and users authentication through Google, but I am having trouble with my `redirectURL`s, as well as translating the callback page I am returned with.

I have dug into the `dpd-passport/index.js` file, and I believe this is the relevant information:

```
var sendResponse = function(ctx, err, config) {
var sessionData = ctx.session.data;
var returnUrl = (ctx.req.cookies && ctx.req.cookies.get('_passportReturnUrl')) || null;

if(returnUrl) {
    var redirectURL = url.parse(returnUrl, true);

    // only append if not disabled
    if(!config.disableReturnParams) {
        // delete search so that query is used
        delete redirectURL.search;

        // make sure query is inited
        redirectURL.query = redirectURL.query || {};
        if(err) {
            redirectURL.query.success = false;
            redirectURL.query.error = err;
        } else {
            // append user + session id to the redirect url
            redirectURL.query.success = true;

            if(!config.disableSessionId) {
                redirectURL.query.sid = sessionData.id;
                redirectURL.query.uid = sessionData.uid;
            }
        }
    }

    var redirectURLString = '';
    try {
        redirectURLString = url.format(redirectURL);
    } catch(ex) {
        console.warn('An error happened while formatting the redirectURL', ex);
    }

    // redirect the user
    ctx.res.setHeader("Location", redirectURLString);
    ctx.res.statusCode = 302;

    ctx.done(null, 'This page has moved to ' + redirectURLString);
    } else {
        if(err) {
            ctx.res.statusCode = 401;
            console.error(err);
            return ctx.done('bad credentials');
        } else {
            ctx.done(err, { path: sessionData.path, id: sessionData.id, uid: sessionData.uid });
        }
    }
};
```

After successfully authenticating, I am given a `returnUrl` of:

`http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback?code=4/l4o-H2F4QKJ5tdKbVbGfWygTGRvhHgr9zrHWImFFKdM#`

with an body of:

`{"path":"/users","id":"d03c0faccfe41134c193266afef979c5af33adf935aeff45844b0f9473dee4ab1fbd1114240e13ea9a542785da3845cfec984e3a5b8cb188d6c595b6fc39a726","uid":"747f97a9bcfa9811"}`

which seems to me like my results are hitting the final `else` statement in the topmost code block.

If this is true, then my `returnUrl` is `NULL`.

Tracing back the `returnUrl` code in the dpd-passport file, it looks like it should be grabbing this from cookies in the follow snippet:

```
if(ctx.query.redirectURL && this.config.allowedRedirectURLs) {
    try {
        this.regEx = this.regEx || new RegExp(this.config.allowedRedirectURLs, 'i');

        if(ctx.query.redirectURL.match(this.regEx)) {
            // save this info into the users session, so that we can access it later (even if the user was redirected to facebook)
            if (ctx.res.cookies) ctx.res.cookies.set('_passportReturnUrl', ctx.query.redirectURL);
        } else {
            debug(ctx.query.redirectURL, 'did not match', this.config.allowedRedirectURLs);
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        debug('Error parsing RedirectURL Regex!', ex);
    }
}
```

To add to this, I have my `allowedRedirectUrls` in the config as:

```
^http://localhost:3000/.*$
```

I am at a loss and am hoping there is something obvious that I am missing.

I have seen the passport routes and authentication strategies similar to the following, but have been unsuccessful in implementing this into dpd-passport:

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

To add to this all, I am using ui-router/AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to supply the redirectURL to dpd-passport through the link that starts the oauth procedure:

```
http://localhost:2403/auth/google?redirectURL=http://localhost
```